# Call a Javascript function after delete data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new with php language and I've a system that is already running, and it is working like this, I've a page called consultas.php and on this page I've a Javascript function, and in another file called delete.php I've a php function that delete a record from database, so it's already running but I'd like to run the function that is on consultas.php after the function that is on delete.php is done, so what can I do it?

so i´m try to explain better, on the page consultas.php I´ve a table with the data from database and at each line from this table I´ve 2 buttons, one to delete and one to edit, so on the delete button it calls the function delete that is on the delete.php, so all the process to delete happens there and after delete it calls the consultas.php again cause that page is the main page of the system cause all the records are there, and it is already working, but after that function delete that is on delete.php has ended i´d like to call the javascript function that is on the consultas.php, but i dont know how can I do this....

so the javascript function that I have is this:

```
 Swal.fire({
 position: 'top',
 type: 'success',
 title: 'Registro excluido com sucesso!',
 showConfirmButton: false,
 timer: 1500
 })
```

and this code are on the consultas.php because is on this page that i need to show this message, but i need to run this code just the code that is in another file, in this case on the delete.php works fine....so the code that I´ve on delete.php is like this:

```
    <?php

include_once 'conexao.php';

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$comandoSQL = $conectaDB->query("delete from chamados where id='$id'");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conectaDB)>0){     

     header("Location:../consultas.php");
}
 ?>
```

resuming, i wanna it works like this: when I click on the button, it calls a function delete that is on delete.php and pass a parameter for it, and there this function execute the delete, after delete it calls the page consultas.php and just then i´d like to show the message that the record was deleted with success...got it? is it more clear now? i hope yes :D

Somebody can help me?

Since then thanks for any help

Comment: How does `consultas.php` call `delete.php`? Does it use AJAX? If it does, you can run the function in the `onreadystatechange` handler for the AJAX request.

Comment: anybody can help me?